# Why is this SQL valid?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table table1
(
    abool boolean
);

create table table2
(
    astring varchar
);



select *
from table1
where (
          select abool
          from (select astring from table2 limit 1) x
      );
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b2f9ae/6

Can someone make sense of the select, and more specifically the sub select, in which it looks like abool is selected from a result set that only contains the astring column?

I mean, I see what happens, abool actually refers to table1, but to me it looks wrong.

And if someone can point me to a more general principle that explains this I'd be thanful.

Comment: Qualify all columns, and you'll see. (Good programming practice!)

Comment: It is allowed because that is how SQL is defined. A derived table also has access to the table(s) from the outer from clause. Otherwise you couldn't make correlated sub-queries.

Comment: If `abool` is not found in the current scope, it is searched in the parent scope. So `select abool` becomes `select table1.abool`.

Comment: It looks like the query selects all true rows from table1 if table2 is not empty. I would rather write it as an EXISTS query to make it obvious.

Comment: As mentioned you should always *always* use aliases and clearly reference each table, otherwise you end up with the confusion you find yourself in, if you were to use `x.abool` then immediately you would see the issue.

Comment: @jarlh and Stu. Like I wrote, I understand that abool actually refers to table1.abool, so wether or not I make this explicit in the query doesn't add to or remove to my understanding.
The thing I found weird is that you can write a query where it reads like your are selecting a column FROM a resultset that doesn't contain the column. Obviously correct SQL (as pointed out by other responders), even though it's incorrect english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it possible? All four queries are logical equivalent:

```sql
select *
from table1
where abool

select *
from table1
where (select abool)
    
select *
from table1
where (select abool from (select 1) sub)

select *
from table1
where (select abool from (select 1 from table2 limit 1) sub)
```

Does the query make sense? Only if you really want to make life harder for your coworkers or play a trick on them.